# How to solve this error occurred during the installation of ATD plugin on Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins

When trying to install the ADT plugin following Android Developper Site' [instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) on a freshly installed Eclipse, I obtained the following error message:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
HTTP Server 'Bad Gateway' : http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_16.0.1.v201112150204-238534.jar
HttpClient connection error response code 502.
```

Is there a workaround allowing me to install the plugin?

Comment: I suspect this is the issue with your internal Firewal contact you administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue on my local pc, no issues with firewall at all, I actually turned it completely off for this.

Nothing seemed to work, until I read on another help forum that it was actually built for Helios version of eclipse, so I gave that a try and it worked first go!

I don't understand how it can make a difference as its a server return code and nothing to do with the client setup, but as worked for me when everything else failed.

I used win32 version http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2, I recommend giving it a try if you are out of options.

The speed was another thing altogether though, it was still terribly slow.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it like you request `http://dl-ssl.google.com` has some problem, please check the internet and try again, if it also dont work, try using `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` this new update address to get ADT.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and attempting to update/reinstall wasn't working.

What ended up fixing it was, I went into my eclipse directory and deleted the adt folders and jar files under /plugins/ then reopened eclipse and reinstalled all the ADT plugins.

Everything is working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem very easily.

**Go to** Control Panel **->** Network and Sharing Center **->** Windows Firewall **->** Turn off Windows Firewall

And try to install again and see the magic :)